# Insert image file to spreadsheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, image, file, insert

I have over 1,000 images in google docs which are name with students names as listed in a google sheet (in some case a "(1,2 etc)" is used when there are multiple files with the same name (I am also in the process of separating [Same name files] these in different folders)

How can I get Google sheets to insert the image file based on the name in the cell eg E5 John, Brown Doe
Image file name John, Brown Doe.jpg (in a google doc folder name pictures)

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets - please fix your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Adapt this to your needs.  Say we have in column **A**:

[image]

Running this:

```
Sub InstallPictures_2()
    Dim i As Long, v As String, shp As Shape
    For i = 1 To 1000
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If v = "" Then Exit For
        With ActiveSheet.Pictures
            .Insert(v).Select
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)
            shp.Top = Cells(i, "B").Top
            shp.Left = Cells(i, "B").Left
            shp.Height = 100
            shp.Width = 100
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: Nice. I could work with this but not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I really need e.g. A1 [Brown, John Doe] image loaded from Google docs folder "...Brown, John Doe.jpg". Incidentally I am having lookup operation issues so I am also looking for reliable free alternatives in the Google environment